# What is a deployment package in Android Studio

Tags: android

I have just completed my android project for a class that I'm taking.  Part of the requirements include: Submit your performance assessment by including all Android project files, APK, and signed apk files in one zipped.zip file.  So to create the APK file I just went to build>Build APK.  To create the signed APK, I went to build>Generate Signed APK where I created a key store and whatnot. The final requirement of the project says: Provide screenshots to demonstrate that you have created a deployment package.  I have no idea what they are asking me to do.  I was hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction as to what they are asking?  Do they want me to run the app and take pictures of it or do they want pictures of the APK files?  I'm still really new to android so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Ask whoever is teaching the class. "Deployment package" is not a common  phrase in Android app development.